# Need help using d3.js to create Stacked Bar Chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am currently trying to convert this (mbostock.github.com/d3/ex/stack.html) vertical stacked bar chart using d3.js to a horizontal stacked bar chart, but I have had no luck.  if anyone has an example of a horizontally stacked bar chart from d3.js or knows how to modify the following code correctly or point me in the correct direction that would be a great help.

```
var margin = 20,
 width = 960,
 height = 500 - .5 - margin,
 mx = m,
 my = d3.max(data, function(d) {
   return d3.max(d, function(d) {
     return d.y0 + d.y;
   });
 }),
 mz = d3.max(data, function(d) {
   return d3.max(d, function(d) {
     return d.y;
  });
 }),
 x = function(d) { return d.x * width / mx; },
 y0 = function(d) { return height - d.y0 * height / my; },
 y1 = function(d) { return height - (d.y + d.y0) * height / my; },
 y2 = function(d) { return d.y * height / mz; }; // or `my` to not rescale

var vis = d3.select("#chart")
.append("svg")
.attr("width", width)
.attr("height", height + margin);

var layers = vis.selectAll("g.layer")
.data(data)
.enter().append("g")
.style("fill", function(d, i) { return color(i / (n - 1)); })
.attr("class", "layer");

var bars = layers.selectAll("g.bar")
.data(function(d) { return d; })
.enter().append("g")
.attr("class", "bar")
.attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + x(d) + ",0)"; });

 bars.append("rect")
.attr("width", x({x: .9}))
.attr("x", 0)
.attr("y", height)
.attr("height", 0)
 .transition()
.delay(function(d, i) { return i * 10; })
.attr("y", y1)
.attr("height", function(d) { return y0(d) - y1(d); });
```

Answer (score 1):

The trick is: treat it almost the same as a vertical stacked bar chart, but invert the x and y values before stacking, and then back again once stacked. Note the comments in the code below.

My blog post about this: http://datashaman.github.io/2014/01/26/horizontal-stacked-bar-chart-d3/

Demo of the code below: http://bl.ocks.org/datashaman/8621955

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/datashaman/rBfy5/2/

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <style>
        .bar {
        }
        .axis path,
        .axis line {
            fill: none;
            stroke: black;
            shape-rendering: crispEdges;
        }
        .axis text {
            font-family: sans-serif;
            font-size: 11px;
        }

        #tooltip {
            position: absolute;
            text-align: center;
            width: 40px;
            height: auto;
            padding: 10px;
            background-color: white;
            -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
            -moz-border-radius: 10px;
            border-radius: 10px;
            -webkit-box-shadow: 4px 4px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
            -moz-box-shadow: 4px 4px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
            box-shadow: 4px 4px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
            pointer-events: none;
        }

        #tooltip.hidden {
            display: none;
        }

        #tooltip p {
            margin: 0;
            font-family: sans-serif;
            font-size: 16px;
            line-height: 20px;
        }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>

        <div id="tooltip" class="hidden">
            <p><span id="value">100</span></p>
        </div>

        <script>
        var margins = {
                top: 12,
                left: 48,
                right: 24,
                bottom: 24
            },
            legendPanel = {
                width: 240
            },
            width = 700 - margins.left - margins.right - legendPanel.width,
            height = 100 - margins.top - margins.bottom,
            dataset = [
                {
                    data: [
                        { month: 'Aug', count: 123 },
                        { month: 'Sep', count: 234 },
                        { month: 'Oct', count: 345 }
                    ],
                    name: 'Series #1'
                },
                {
                    data: [
                        { month: 'Aug', count: 235 },
                        { month: 'Sep', count: 267 },
                        { month: 'Oct', count: 573 }
                    ],
                    name: 'Series #2'
                }

            ],
            series = dataset.map(function(d) { return d.name; }),
            dataset = dataset.map(function(d) {
                return d.data.map(function(o, i) {
                    // Structure it so that your numeric
                    // axis (the stacked amount) is y
                    return {
                        y: o.count,
                        x: o.month
                    };
                });
            }),
            stack = d3.layout.stack();

        stack(dataset);

        var dataset = dataset.map(function(group) {
            return group.map(function(d) {
                // Invert the x and y values, and y0 becomes x0
                return {
                    x: d.y,
                    y: d.x,
                    x0: d.y0
                };
            });
        }),
        svg = d3.select('body')
            .append('svg')
                .attr('width', width + margins.left + margins.right + legendPanel.width)
                .attr('height', height + margins.top + margins.bottom)
            .append('g')
                .attr('transform', 'translate(' + margins.left + ',' + margins.top + ')'),
        xMax = d3.max(dataset, function(group) {
            return d3.max(group, function(d) {
                return d.x + d.x0;
            });
        }),
        xScale = d3.scale.linear()
            .domain([0, xMax])
            .range([0, width]),
        months = dataset[0].map(function(d) { return d.y; }),
        _ = console.log(months),
        yScale = d3.scale.ordinal()
            .domain(months)
            .rangeRoundBands([0, height], .1),
        xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
            .scale(xScale)
            .orient('bottom'),
        yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
            .scale(yScale)
            .orient('left'),
        colours = d3.scale.category10(),
        groups = svg.selectAll('g')
            .data(dataset)
            .enter()
            .append('g')
                .style('fill', function(d, i) {
                    return colours(i);
                }),
        rects = groups.selectAll('rect')
            .data(function(d) { return d; })
            .enter()
                .append('rect')
                    .attr('x', function(d) { return xScale(d.x0); })
                    .attr('y', function(d, i) { return yScale(d.y); })
                    .attr('height', function(d) { return yScale.rangeBand(); })
                    .attr('width', function(d) { return xScale(d.x); })
                    .on('mouseover', function(d) {
                        var xPos = parseFloat(d3.select(this).attr('x')) / 2 + width / 2;
                        var yPos = parseFloat(d3.select(this).attr('y')) + yScale.rangeBand() / 2;

                        d3.select('#tooltip')
                            .style('left', xPos + 'px')
                            .style('top', yPos + 'px')
                            .select('#value')
                            .text(d.x);

                        d3.select('#tooltip').classed('hidden', false);
                    })
                    .on('mouseout', function() {
                        d3.select('#tooltip').classed('hidden', true);
                    })

        svg.append('g')
            .attr('class', 'axis')
            .attr('transform', 'translate(0,' + height + ')')
            .call(xAxis);

        svg.append('g')
            .attr('class', 'axis')
            .call(yAxis);

        svg.append('rect')
            .attr('fill', 'yellow')
            .attr('width', 160)
            .attr('height', 30 * dataset.length)
            .attr('x', width + margins.left)
            .attr('y', 0);

        series.forEach(function(s, i) {
            svg.append('text')
                .attr('fill', 'black')
                .attr('x', width + margins.left + 8)
                .attr('y', i * 24 + 24)
                .text(s);
            svg.append('rect')
                .attr('fill', colours(i))
                .attr('width', 60)
                .attr('height', 20)
                .attr('x', width + margins.left + 90)
                .attr('y', i * 24 + 6);
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: how can i make the sorting on this chart

Answer (score -1):

Try Frank Guerino's examples:
http://bl.ocks.org/2141479 - horizontal bar chart
and 
http://bl.ocks.org/2354192 - Multiple D3 Top Down and Bottom Up Stacked Bar Charts (without d3.layout.stack)
Combine the horizontal code with the Crimea example or Multiple D3 Top Down example and you should be on your track. Mainly what you have to look for is how to calculate the coordinates right in the horizontal setup. The rest is the same like any other stack example.
Best regards!

Comment: Also take a look at this: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/d3-js/horizontal$20stack/d3-js/NnIK9weFbQg/gQhUQlNtdz4J